# Editable divisions instead of Textarea. input is not getting submitted ! PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

If i use

```
<div contentEditable="true" name="content"></div>
```

instead of Textarea in the form i'm not able to submit the input taken in above editable division.

I'm using editable division because i want to add  images at run time in the input editable division.

so is there any way to submit an input taken in editable division??

I'm using PHP as server side language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the values of input elements get submitted with a form.

Use a script on the client to put the contents of the `div` into a hidden field when the form is submitted.

For example:

```
<form action="/blah.php" method="post" onsubmit="prepForm()">
    <div contentEditable="true" id="editor"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content">
</form>
```

...

```
<script>
function prepForm() {
    document.getElementById('content').value = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use JavaScript to store the `.innerHTML` of your div in a hidden field when submitting the form.